# В процедуре запрос дольше чем по отдельности

Tags: sql, sql-server

В процедуру на вход приходит параметр @OPERATION, после чего в зависимости от операции выполняются действия.
Например если делаю фэйковую операцию @OPERATION, 
где пишу просто выбрать одну запись из самой простой таблицы - результат - 27 секунд.
Тот же самый запрос отдельно - меньше секунды.

Подозреваю, что из-за того, что в некоторых if(@OPERATION== содержится код использующий связанный сервер, но почему SQL пытается компилировать всю процедуру? Почему он не выполняет только нужный код?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [spx.Text]
@OPERATION varchar(150)=''
@UUID varchar(250)='',
AS
BEGIN

    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    IF (@OPERATION = 'SelectOr')
    BEGIN        
        select name, 
        code
        from orders S 
        where s.Complete=1
    END

    IF (@OPERATION ='TakeJournalPos')
    begin
        select JCode[Код],JName [Наименования],Qty [Количество]
        FROM [linkedserver].[mainbase].[dbo].Journal
    end

    IF (@OPERATION = 'SendUuid')
    BEGIN
         exec [linkedserver].[mainbase].[dbo].spxUuidAdd @UUID
         select @str
    end
END
```

Получается что при вызове обычного SelectOr например, во первых при отсутствующей связи с линкед сервером падает запрос полностью, ну и вот похоже из-за этого же и увеличивается время запроса.

Comment: Добавьте пожалуйста, код который по вашему мнению не работает или работает с ошибкой.

Comment: @rafnsvartr  я вырезал кусочек :) Там есть ещё использование xml, которое тоже возможно чудит, но факт в том, что на двух из 3 машинах работает нормально...

Comment: Попробуйте добавить проверку состояния сервера `sp_testlinkedserver [ @servername ] = servername`